# Why does an unused class/method not get included in object file when compiled with clang?

Tags: c++, clang

I have an issue with some C++ code I'm working on. The following file:

```cpp
// test.cpp
class Base64
{
public:
    static const char *to_string()
    {
        return "Base64";
    }
};
```

...when compiled with `clang++ -c test.cpp -o test.o && nm test.o`, contains **absolutely no symbols**. In other words, the static `Base64::to_string()` method has been "optimized away", presumably.

*However*, if I change my little program to look like this instead:

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base64
{
public:
    static const char *to_string()
    {
        return "Base64";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Base64::to_string();
}
```

...it looks miuch better (de-mangling of C++ symbols courtesy of http://demangler.com/):

```
$ clang++ -c test.cpp -o test.o && nm test.o | curl --data-urlencode input@- http://demangler.com/raw
U __cxa_atexit
0000000000000000 t __cxx_global_var_init
                 U __dso_handle
0000000000000030 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_test.cpp
0000000000000000 r .L.str
0000000000000000 T main
0000000000000000 W Base64::to_string()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::Init()
                 U std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
                 U std::cout
0000000000000000 b std::__ioinit
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
```

The `Base64::to_string()` exists in this case, and I presume the reason for this is that my `main()` method calls it.

Is this by design? Is this a `clang` peculiarity (I'll be honest and say that I haven't tested the exact same program with GNU `g++`)? It is a problem for me since I'm writing "library" code and include multiple files in my compilation (`clang file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp`). Symbols defined in one of the C++ files gets removed so that the linking files.

(I know this - compiling multiple files at once - is not an optimal way to compile C/C++ code, but I have my reasons - let's not get sidetracked by that now. Either way, the symbols are removed when simply compiling *one* single file, as described in the example above, so moving to a more "proper" setup here wouldn't help with this problem anyway.)

Comment: Might it be a weak symbol not displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any functions defined inside a class, including static member functions are implicitly [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline), which makes them *inline functions*.
*Inline functions* can be defined in multiple translation units (TUs, i.e. `.cpp` files) as long as every TU which uses the function has a definition, and all definitions are identical.

###### Compiler behavior for *inline functions*

- if `Base64::to_string()` is unused, the compiler can choose not to emit it, because if another TU is using that entity, it must have its own identical definition, or
- if `Base64::to_string()` is used anywhere, it may be emitted because the compiler uses it, but
- if you compile with optimizations enabled and `Base64::to_string()` is always inlined when used, it might not be emitted

#### Solution

Define your static member function out-of-line:

```cpp
class Base64
{
public:
    // implicitly inline, won't be emitted if unused
    static const char *to_string()
    {
        return "Base64";
    }
};

class Base128
{
public:
    static const char *to_string();
};

// out-of-line definition, implicitly extern linkage, must be emitted
const char *Base128::to_string()
{
    return "Base128";
}
```

###### Output

```
Base128::to_string():
        lea     rax, [rip + .L.str]
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Base128"
```

*See [live example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bbY7E9Pao)*

Comment: Minor point: they have **internal** linkage; there is no such thing as "inline" linkage.

Comment: @PeteBecker actually this is also wrong, `inline` has no effect on function linkage. See https://eel.is/c++draft/full#dcl.inline-note-1. I've updated the question to avoid discussing linkage. I believe `static` has no effect on linkage here either, so all function should have external linkage.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JanSchultke, this did indeed solve the problem. I've obviously been using C# and Java for too long (where defining methods inside the class is "the way" to do things). I was aware of the fact that I need the prototype definitions to be able to use the function from another class, but I didn't remember/wasn't aware of this important distinction between inline functions and out-of-line... Highly appreciated!